# FFMPEG (libav) I get pts = 0 on every video frame while i decode video file with B-frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm developing simple video player.
When i test my application on sample video with B-frames i get message:
**[mpeg4 @ 0x556b56585d40] Video uses a non-standard and wasteful way to store B-frames ('packed B-frames'). Consider using the mpeg4_unpack_bframes bitstream filter without encoding but stream copy to fix it.**
Wheh i test my application on sample video without B-frames i have no any problem.

I can't synchronize playback with PTS = 0 or random on every B-frame
LOG is below:

> Format avi, duration 9223372036854775808 us
> Sample format:AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP
> Video Codec:MPEG-4 part 2 ID:12 bit_rate:15034224
> Audio Codec:MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) ID:86017 bit_rate:320000
> input bitrate: 48000
> input audio nchanels: 2
> input samples in frame per 1ch 1152
> alsa: audio device with PCM name: 'default' is used
> alsa: PCM state: PREPARED
> alsa: set nchannels: 2
> alsa: set stereo sound
> alsa: set bitrate: 48000
> alsa: set nframes per buffer: 64
> alsa: set period time for buffer(in useconds): 1333
> breakpointstart of frame decoding loop
> read_frame: got audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP size 4608
> m_syncmaster:eUndef3 eVideoMaster
> Last audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE size 0
> read_frame: got audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP size 4608
> m_syncmaster eAudioMaster
> Last audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE size 0
> read_frame: got audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP size 4608
> m_syncmaster eAudioMaster
> Last audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE size 0
> read_frame: got audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP size 4608
> m_syncmaster eAudioMaster
> Last audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE size 0
> read_frame: got audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP size 4608
> ......
> m_syncmaster eAudioMaster
> Last audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE size 0
> [mpeg4 @ 0x556b56585d40] Video uses a non-standard and wasteful way to store B-frames ('packed B-frames'). Consider using the mpeg4_unpack_bframes bitstream filter without encoding but stream copy to fix it.
> read_frame: got video frame format 0 size 1448637632
> convert video Frame I (1) pts 0 dts 1 key_frame 1 delay 0.000000 data size 6220800
> read_frame: Last video frame format -1 size 1448637632
> read_frame: got audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP size 4608
> m_syncmaster eAudioMaster
> Last audio frame format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_NONE size 0
> read_frame: got video frame format 0 size 1448637632
> convert video Frame B (2) pts 0 dts 2 key_frame 0 delay 0.000000 data size 6220800
> read_frame: Last video frame format -1 size 1448637632

How can i fix Iit ?
FFMPEG(libav) version 5.1

I try to google this problem and have found a hint: mpeg4_unpack_bframe, but I don't understand how to implement it.